# dynamic page caching- show redirected html cache page or show the dynamic page?

Tags: caching, dynamic

would like your comments.

Eg: When user first visit www.testing.com/productdetailpage.asp

I will use caching- store the whole page into productdetailpage.html

When the user go to reopen productdetailpage.asp, user will be redirected to www.testing.com/productdetailpage.html

It means they will see productdetailpage.html, not .asp

Is this a good way? Any implication in terms of SEO and other part? 
Will it be better to read datas from .html into .asp and show the final page as .asp all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do that you want to specify that the asp version is the canonical version, or [your page rank will suffer](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) (or rather, not gain the benefit of Google seeing the html and the asp versions as the same).

I'd only go down this route if you are suffering serious performance problems with your asp version.